# Change of basis matrix for orthogonal bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are orthonormal bases for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the change of basis matrix $P$ from $B_1$ to $B_2$ is an orthogonal matrix.

I'm a bit stuck.  I started with this: Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Then $[x]_{B_2}^t[y]_{B_2} = (P[x]_{B_1})^tP[y]_{B_1} = [x]_{B_1}^tP^tP[y]_{B_1}$.  I want to show that $P^tP = I_n$.  I know I need to apply the fact that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are orthonormal, but I don't see how to apply that to this expression.  Am I approaching this properly or is there a better way to think about it?

Comment: A matrix is orthogonal iff its column vectors are orthonormal.

Answer (score 4):

Because $B_1$ and $B_2$ are orthonormal bases for $\mathbb{R}^n$, corresponding matrices (when expressed in a standard basis) are both orthogonal matrices. Since $B_2=PB_1$, $P=B_2 B_1^{-1}$ holds, and it is quite clear that $P$ is also an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Though your idea is not the only possible approach, it works. Just let $x$ and $y$ independently run thought all the standard basis vectors, and you equation says that all $n^2$ entries of $P^t P$ are equal to the corresponding entry of the identity matrix.

Comment: Hmm... I hope that works but don't quite see it, since different bases are used on each side of the equation.  Where has the orthonormality of the bases been applied?

Comment: I may have misread your approach. I think you would need that the scalar product of two coordinate vectors on an orthonormal basis remains unchanged when transforming to coordinates on another orthonormal basis; this is so similar to what you are proving that it seems like a circular argument. Anyway it seems much easier to do this using matrix equations, see the other answer.